# How to traverse through a dictionary of dictionaries and extract values that match list elements in python?

Tags: python

I have two lists like this:

```
l = [ 'of', 'in', 'fly']

l2 = ['starbucks', 'the', 'and', '.', ',', 'from', 'to']
```

and a dictionary like this:

```
d = { of : {in : 1, and : 2, to: 0}, in : { of : 2,  and : 5, to : 3}, and : {of : 3, in: 6, to: 2}, to: {and: 1, of: 0, in: 3}}
```

I want to traverse from list `l`, and if there is a key of the word in the list l in the dictionary d, then traverse list l2 and match the keys in the inner dictionary (i.e., the value for the matched key from outer dictionary) and only extract those key values from the inner dictionary, as the values for that key from outer dictionary.
And if word is not in d, then add it to new_dict giving it a value 0.

Like for the above I want an output like this:

```
new_dict = {of : [2, 0] , in : [5, 3], fly: 0}
```

since 'and' and 'to' are the only words that match with the inner dictionary.

I was doing something like this:

```
for k in l:
    if k in d:
        new_d[k]=d[k]
        d_values = new_d.values()
        for k2 in l2:
            if k2 in d_values:
                t[k2] = d_values[k2]
                temp[k] = t
    else temp[k] = 0
```

But I'm getting `temp = {}`. Why is this so? How can I fix this?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham : fly exists in l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
new__d = defaultdict(list)
for k in l:
    if k in d: 
        for k2, vals in d[k].iteritems(): # list element is in d so get that keys items
            if k2 in l2:
                new__d[k].append(vals) 
    else:
        new__d[k] = 0  # presuming you want a default value of 0 for list elements that are not in d
print(new__d)

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'fly': 0, 'of': [2, 0], 'in': [5, 3]})
```

I used `defaultdict` as there are keys repeating so we need to append the values or else they will be overwritten.

If you insist on not using a `defaultdict`, you can use `dict.setdefault` but it is less efficient:

```
new__d = {}
for k in l:
    if k in d:
        for k2, vals in d[k].iteritems():
            if k2 in l2:
                new__d.setdefault(k,[])
                new__d[k].append(vals)
    else:
        new__d[k] = 0
print(new__d)
```

Comment: The output that I'm getting is : {'of': 0, 'in': 3}, I want {of : {and : 2, to: 0}, in : {and : 5, to : 3}, fly: 0}, I'm okay with getting this too: { of : [2,0], in : [5,3], fly: 0}

Comment: I don't get where fly comes from my answer will give you `{'of': [2, 0], 'in': [5, 3]}`

Comment: Thanks it gives me the required answer, but is it possible to not get 'defaultdict(<type 'list'>,' in the output?

Comment: `print(dict(new_dict))` defaultdict is the most efficient, it behaves just like a normal dict so there should be no reason not to use it

Comment: Could you show me that? I actually need to proceed forth and this is just an intermediate result that I need. I have never used defaultdict previously.

Comment: there is no difference Martha, use it as you would a normal dict